# How to place a View to the right of a TextView

Tags: android, view

I would like to place a `TextView` and another `View` next to it. Like this:

```
|                             |
|[TextView][View]             |
|                             |
```

The `TextView` might have a long text. In that case, I would like to use ellipsis so the `View` is not pushed out of the screen (or whatever layout contains them) nor deformed.

```
|                             |
|[TextView with long...][View]|
|                             |
```

So I want the `View` to be next to `TextView` while the `TextView` takes as much space as needed (and no more than needed) without pushing the `View` out of the screen/container when the text is too long (in that case, I'd like to cut the text with ellipsis).

How could I do that?

I was thinking of calculating the positions and sizes of the views but seems a bit complicated. Maybe there's some simpler solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a LinearLayout with horizontal orientation as [blackbelt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501696/blackbelt) suggested, but setting its width to wrap_content

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:text="unknown sized view" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fixed sized view"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks man! That's the simple solution I was looking for! I didn't know the difference of using weights with a wrap_content or match_parent container.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an horizontal `LinearLayout` with width `math_parent`, which contains two children. The left TextView will have `0dp` of width and `weight` 1, the View will have `wrap_content` for the width. For the dots at the end you can use `android:ellipsize`

Comment: Almost! In this case I would have `|[TextView short_______][View]|` even when the `TextView` text is short. I would like to have `|[TextView short][View]_______|`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64357/discussion-between-vince-emigh-and-ferran-maylinch).

Answer (score 0):

In the parent layout of TextView and View, set layout_weightsum = 3.

In TextView, set layout_weight=2 and in View, set layout_weight=1.

Irrespective of the length of the text in textview, view and textview will be rendered properly.

Comment: That way the `TextView` would be exactly twice the size of the `View`, and that's not what I'm looking for. I want the `TextView` to take as much space as possible while the `View` is on the right, completely visible and not distorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RelativeLayout` with `android:layout_toRightOf` , according to the [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) at developer.android.com it is the exact same thing that you've been looking for.

Comment: I've tried that, but if the `TextView` is too long, the `View` has no room left and appears broken, like this way: `|[TextView with long t...][V]|`.

Answer (score 0):

you could try putting both views inside a horizontal LinearLayout and setting **android:maxWidth** for the TextView, that way the View will remain on the right side of the TextView when it's short

> |[TextView short][View]_______|

, and when it's long, the TextView will only expand as much as you set its maximum width.

> |[TextView with long t...][View]|

Comment: What would be the value of `maxWidth`?

Comment: you should set the value depending on your design and screen size.

Comment: That's what seems complicated so I would like to avoid, as I say in my question. Do you have any idea on how to do that? Those views are inside a container and I don't know the size of View on the right because it has some text inside (it's another TextView, in fact, but I want it to display the full text without ellipsis).